# Bigquery import asks for pyparsing in shell run

Tags: python, google-bigquery, setuptools, pyparsing

I get this error **"ImportError: The 'pyparsing' package is required"** after trying to run  .py file with `from google.cloud import bigquery` line. Import was working before and is still working in the Jupyter Notebook or in Ipython.

I looked at existing options here and tried:

1. pip install pyparsing
2. downgrade setuptools
3. uninstall pyparsing and setuptools and installing them back
4. uninistall and purge pip and install it back

Does anyone have suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It is silly, but happens to me from time to time. ***Do not name files in your project like*** - `html.py` =) . It was in one of the folders of my project. Really annoying, but nevertheless, hope it will help someone. Maybe you have same problem with different file name, but look up for files with common use names!)

Comment: Don't feel too bad, this is a very common mistake, and easy to make. Over time, you'll get  to know which names to avoid when naming your .py files.